# Access to origin/develop branch in GitKraken

Tags: git, gitkraken

Probably a newbie question, sorry. I cloned a git repository while there was only an origin/master branch. Now someone has added an origin/develop branch but I find no way of pulling this new branch or even just looking to the remote structure so I could find out any new branches that I might pull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitKraken usually auto-fetches changes from the remotes. You can set up the *Auto-Fetch Interval* in *File->Preferences*. You can also fetch manually by clicking on the small arrow to the right of the *Pull* toolbar icon and clicking *Fetch All*.

New branches will then appear in the *Remote* section on the left side, between *Local* and *Stashes* sections. You might have to expand it by clicking on the *Remote* title bar to see the branches.

You can check out a local branch tracking the remote by just double-clicking the remote branch in the *Remotes* section.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I had the auto fetch set to 1 (default when installing) and I think I tried to do a fetch all (and also a fetch origin in the left panel on the origin node) without success. I finally made a "git fetch origin" in command line that worked.